# Avalanche breakdown voltage, how does it start?

Tags: semiconductors

I would like to learn about the avalanche effect. I understand what goes on in the avalance effect, but I can't understand how it starts.

For the avalanche effect to start, an electron (the first) must have enough energy to go to the depletion zone and knock the electron from the atom.

For me it is a little hard to understand. How did that electron get enough energy to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every diode has a (possibly tiny) leakage current when reverse biased. For typical silicon diodes, the reverse leakage is on the order of a few femtoamps (10<sup>-15</sup>'s A). I don't know the typical leakage current for an avalanche diode off the top of my head, but it is likely within a couple of orders of magnitude of this value. And even a femtoamp is still something on the order of 6000 carriers passing through the depletion region each second.

As the reverse biased is increased, the electric field in the depletion region increases, and this field accelerates the leakage carriers as they pass through the depletion region. Avalanche begins when the acceleration due to the field gives the carriers enough energy to break new carriers loose (*impact ionization* as is mentioned in another answer) when they interact with bound electrons in the depletion region.

Answer (score 4):

Electrons are not all the same energy distribution - some are higher than others. Same with speed of molecules in air at a given temperature. What we see as voltage and current flow (or temperature in air) is an average.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found the answer on [this link](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter4/ch4_5.htm). Here's the citation:

> Avalanche breakdown is caused by impact ionization of electron-hole pairs.

Comment: This only restates what's in the question about having "enough energy to go to the depletion zone and knock the electron from the atom." It doesn't explain where the carriers come from.

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding, the operation of Avalanche diode starts similar to that of Zener diodes. The Zener diode structure has a very narrow depletion region which causes the Electric field in the region to sky rocket in reverse bias conditions, this provides enough energy to the electron to perform quantum tunneling and tunnels into the conduction band of the N-region and holes into the valence band of P-region.

But the Electric field required for Impact ionization aka Avalanche breakdown is much larger. The diode must be designed to endure much higher reverse bias currents to undergo Avalanche breakdown. As you must know, Avalanche breakdown occurs at voltages above 5.5V, at these voltages the electric field across the narrow depletion layer becomes so huge that it provides sufficient kinetic energy to cause "impact ionization" of the lattice. It is to be noted that some Zener breakdown induced conduction do occur in Avalanche diodes as well.

Comment: From what I know, in the case of zener breakdown, because the depletion width is very small, the application of low reverse bias (5 volts or less) will cause a larger field to be set up across the depletion region on the order of $3 x 10^5$V/cm which is far **greater** than that required by Avalanche breakdown. The breakdown voltage is larger for Avalanche but the width is also larger, while a smaller Zener breakdown voltage is across a thin depletion region causing higher electric field. https://circuitglobe.com/difference-between-avalanche-and-zener-breakdown.html